# Magento 2 : Custom payment on place order error "The authorize action is not available."

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

On click place order button we get error message

> "The authorize action is not available."

How to redirect on success page or custom success page. Please help me .
After I click, response message show :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This indicates the payment method against which the error showing is not configured properly.

You can verify it by temporarily disable that custom payment method and check whether you can place an order. After you confirmed the issue is related to the custom payment method, then double check all the configurations related to that custom payment method.

Comment: Download code from here "https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/how-to-add-custom-payment-method-in-magento-2-441"
and enable to admin. This show on frontend checkout payment. I select this payment and click on place order then show this error.

Answer (score 0):

check you config.xml file remove this line or comment this

```
<payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
```

then remove cahche and check again

Answer (score 0):

Open your payment method model and add param to your payment class:

`/**
     * Payment Method feature
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canAuthorize = true;`

This param is false by default

Answer (score 0):

That error shows when you provide no proper data on "Place Order" action.
Try to debug where the problem is.
If you make a frontend processed payment transaction, then you must provide some response data to backend.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution-1:

You have to goto your VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml file path.
In that config.xml file

### Comment this line

<payment_action>authorize</payment_action>

### Solution:2 (add param to your payment class)

Go to your VendorName/ModuleName/Model/PaymentMethod.php

### Add this line to your Model Code

protected $_canAuthorize = 'true';